# How to pass API response as argument to XML element in python?

Tags: python, xml

I want to pass an argument (that I received from an api post) to an XML tag as an element as part of my payload. This is my code after I print the response.

```py
print(response.content)

root = ET.fromstring(response.content)

for x in root.findall("data"):

    print(x.text)

    url = "https://www.example.com"

    payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"">\r\n <Target>$x.text</Target>\r\n"
```

But I get the following error

> XML parsing error: value '$x.text' does not match regular expression facet '[+-]?[0-9]+'

I even tried passing it as &x.text but I get this error-

> XML parsing error: unterminated entity reference 'x.text'

Could someone please help?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using, with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)? It seems the `payload` you have posted is invalid Python syntax, so  wouldn't produce the error you refer to. Also if possible, post a snippet of the XML response so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, the payload is actually an xml input-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BES xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BES.xsd">
 <SourcedFixletAction>
     <Target>$x.text</Target>
 </SourcedFixletAction>
</BES>

Answer (score 0):

This is because you messed up with double quotation marks. So use single quotation marks.

```
payload = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <BES xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BES.xsd"> <SourcedFixletAction> <Target>$x.text</Target> </SourcedFixletAction> </BES>'
```